# Accordion switch images on open and close of siblings

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion

I have an `accordion` with a plus image and minus image in the `HTML` and these images are to be `toggled when the accordion is opened and closed`.

At present when you open and close one accordion it is effectively toggling its plus/minus images and closing any open siblings.

> BUT here's the problem: the image on that sibling being closed will not toggle back to the plus image.

Just wondering if anyone had an idea… thanks!

```js
$('.accordion').hide();

$('.heading').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
    $(this).next().siblings('.accordion').slideUp(400);
});


$('.heading2').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
    $(this).next().siblings('.accordion').slideUp(400);
});                 


$('#minus').hide();
$('#minus2').hide();


$('.heading').on('click', function(){
    "use strict";
    $('#plus').fadeToggle();
    $('#minus').fadeToggle();
});


$('.heading2').on('click', function(){
    "use strict";
    $('#plus2').fadeToggle();
    $('#minus2').fadeToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="heading">
  <h4>LOREM IPSUM</h4>
  <img src="images/plus.png" width="20px" height="20px" alt="" id="plus"/>
  <img src="images/minus.png" width="20px" height="3px" alt="" id="minus"/>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
  <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is 
    reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 
    from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced 
    in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from 
    the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
</div>

<div class="heading2">
  <h4>LOREM IPSUM2</h4>
  <img src="images/plus.png" width="20px" height="20px" alt="" id="plus2"/>
  <img src="images/minus.png" width="20px" height="3px" alt="" id="minus2"/>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
  <p>All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to 
      repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first 
      true generator on the Internet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close the sibling accordion, you have to hide the other accordion's minus and always show the plus.
Please find the snippet below.

If you can use JQuery UI, there is a built in accordion widget: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

```js
$('.accordion').hide();

$('.heading').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
    $(this).next().siblings('.accordion').slideUp(400);
});


$('.heading2').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
    $(this).next().siblings('.accordion').slideUp(400);
});                 


$('#minus').hide();
$('#minus2').hide();


$('.heading').on('click', function(){
    "use strict";
    $('#plus').fadeToggle();
    $('#minus').fadeToggle();
    $('#plus2').fadeIn();
    $('#minus2').fadeOut();
});


$('.heading2').on('click', function(){
    "use strict";
    $('#plus2').fadeToggle();
    $('#minus2').fadeToggle();
    $('#plus').fadeIn();
    $('#minus').fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="heading">
  <h4>LOREM IPSUM</h4>
  <img src="images/plus.png" alt="+" width="20px" height="20px" alt="" id="plus"/>
  <img src="images/minus.png" alt="-" width="20px" height="3px" alt="" id="minus"/>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
  <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is 
    reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 
    from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced 
    in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from 
    the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
</div>

<div class="heading2">
  <h4>LOREM IPSUM2</h4>
  <img src="images/plus.png" alt="+" width="20px" height="20px" alt="" id="plus2"/>
  <img src="images/minus.png" alt="-" width="20px" height="3px" alt="" id="minus2"/>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
  <p>All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to 
      repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first 
      true generator on the Internet.</p>
</div>
```